# Twitter's Bootstrap Popover: Won't work, even when other JS is working ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set up a popover using Twitter's Bootstrap.
I've successfully used other JavaScript (dropdown, and tooltips), but I can't get this one working.

I've got this html inside my page:

```
<a href="#" id="matriz" rel="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" title="A title">hover for popover</a>
```

I've set inside the document body this:

```
<script>
  $(function() { 
    $('#matriz').popover({placement: 'bottom', trigger: 'hover', offset: 1});
  });
</script>
```

I've called the files like this, using hotlinks:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/raw/master/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/raw/master/js/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - if you load the CSS from elsewhere, everything works: http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/5DGef/

Comment: Thanks! It works that way, and it works if I copy/paste the stuff inside the "Css" block in jsfiddle. It´s weird because I´ve already go the correct and complete css file inside my own folder and pinted out ok (it works in all other cases). Weird. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

BTW, it's redundant to use bootstrap-tooltips.js and bootstrap-twipsy.js. Tooltips replaced Twipsy.

Answer (score 1):

The important piece you're missing is the main CSS file, `bootstrap.css`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sn2Zz/

<sup>( I wasn't sure where to hotlink, so I pasted the content of `bootstrap.css`.)</sup>

Particularly, you need the `.popover-*` styles.

Chances are it was "working", but you weren't able to see it because the popup's position in the DOM is right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: To link other scripts / CSS in jsFiddle, use the "Add Resources" item in the menu on the left.

Comment: @Inerdial: I just couldn't find the source of the CSS files on the Bootstrap github site, only .less files... Actually I tried [this](https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css) and it didn't seem to work. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the "I wasn't sure where" bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I do have the bootstrap.css file, and it has all the popover styles..., I don´t have that part od the code at the end of the document, but I´ll try putting it at the very top

Comment: In fact, I´ve added all the needed files, and it still doesn´t work... http://jsfiddle.net/PS3LH/

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but it must have something to do with jsfiddle/github or hotlinking to bootstrap source files. The CSS is obviously not getting loaded (same issue I mentioned above) and [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PS3LH/2/) works by using a `<script>` tag rather than the jsfiddle Resource panel.